# Device Drivers vs the /dev + glibc Interface

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, glibc

I am looking to have the processor read from I2C and store the data in DDR in an embedded system. As I have been looking at solutions, I have been introduced to Linux device drivers as well as the GNU C Library. It seems like for many operations you can perform with the basic Linux drivers you can also perform with basic glibc system calls. I am somewhat confused when one should be used over the other. Both interfaces can be accessed from the user space.

When should I use a kernel driver to access a device like I2C or USB and when should I use the GNU C Library system functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GNU C Library forwards function calls such as `read`, `write`, `ioctl` directly to the kernel.  These functions are just very thin wrappers around the system calls.  You could call the kernel all by yourself using inline assembly, but that is rarely helpful.  So in this sense, all interactions with the kernel driver will go through these glibc functions.

If you have questions about specific interfaces and their trade-offs, you need to name them explicitly.

Comment: What's to stop me from including the proper glibc file in a user application and kmallocing a huge chunk of memory? If they are all just systems calls what is so "privileged" about the kernel space? How is this managed?

Comment: "Usually, i2c devices are controlled by a kernel driver. But it is also
possible to access all devices on an adapter from userspace, through the /dev interface." When would I use the kernel drivers vs the dev interface? Do most peripherals have a device interface?

Answer (score 0):

In ARM:

*Privilege states* are built into the processor and are changed via assembly commands. A memory protection unit, a part of the chip, is configured to disallow access to arbitrary ranges of memory depending on the privilege status.

In the case of the Linux kernel, ALL physical memory is privileged- memory addresses in userspace are virtual (fake) addresses, translated to real addresses once in privileged mode.

So, to access a privileged memory range, the mechanics are like a function call- you set the parameters indicating what you want, and then make a ('SVC')- an interrupt function which removes control of the program from userspace, gives it to the kernel. The kernel looks at your parameters and does what you need.

The standard library basically makes that whole process easier.

Drivers create interfaces to physical memory addresses and provide an API through the SVC call and whatever 'arguments' it's passed.

If physical memory is not reserved by a driver, the kernel generally won't allow anyone to access it.

Accessing physical memory you're not privileged to will cause a "bus error".

BTW: You can use a driver like UIO to put physical memory into userspace.